# Inject Spring Boot Service Into Non-Managed Class

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a set of classes that all extend from my ReportConfig abstract class. Once created, they are currently immutable and not managed by Spring.

However, I'm finding that sometimes I need to perform an action that requires the use of a particular service, but I'm struggling to find the best way to inject these services into my non-managed ReportConfig instances. See below:

```
@Service
public class ReportService() {

    @Autowired
    private SchemaService schemaService;

    @Autowired
    private ExecutionService executionService;

    @Autowired
    private ReportConfigFactory reportConfigFactory;

    public Result executeReport(ReportRequest request) {

        ReportConfig reportConfig = reportConfigFactory.getReportConfig(request);

        reportConfig.validateAgainstSchema(schemaService.getSchemaForDataset(reportConfig.getDataset()));

        executionService.execute(reportConfig.getQuery());

}
```

Now I have no issue with the `dataService.execute()` line, but I do have an issue with the `reportConfig.validateAgainstSchema()` line and I feel an alternative would be something like:

```
reportConfig.validateAgainstSchema(schemaService);
```

But I feel that maybe represents tight coupling.

I'm imagining there's also a way to inject SchemaService straight into ReportConfigs, but not sure if this defeats the object...

Keen to hear your thoughts.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From what I understood from the current design of your application given in question and I am guessing the functionality and thinking about an alternative design,

```
reportConfig.validateAgainstSchema(schemaService.getSchemaForDataset(reportConfig.getDataset()));
```

What you can think of is, if reportconfig is the right place to do `validateAgainstSchema` if not think about changing it.
Is `schemaService` the right place to do `validateAgainstSchema`(I think not) if that is also not the right place to do it, then create a `SchemaValidator` or something similar. 
This is something that I could think of with the information you have given me.

If `validateAgainstSchema` is not overridden by any child classes of `ReportConfig` and possibility is very rare then you should definitely think of moving it to a different class. The reason I say this is that if the schema changes then you should not have to change the `reportConfig` class

If its overridden and there are multiple implementations then one way would be to use a validator factory to get the validator and do validation. I don't even know if this suits your use case but this is all I can come up with the information in the question.
Hope it helps you in someway.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have to inject services into config classes ?  Could you just not pass what config need directly ?

Alternatively if you must you can use setter based injection to autowire the service into ReportConfig abstract class or you can use method injection.

Something like

[`Setter based Injection`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-setter-injection)

```
public abstract class ReportConfig {

   protected SchemaService schemaService;

   protected final setSchemaService(SchemaService schemaService) {
    this.schemaService = schemaService;
   }  

}
```

[`Method Injection`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-method-injection)

```
public class BeanUtility implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    protected SchemaService getSchemaService() {
        return this.applicationContext.getBean("schemaService", SchemaService.class);
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sagar, I dont specifically want to inject the schema service into the `ReportConfig`, it's just that each `ReportConfig` instance is the only object that knows how is should be validated when provided with a schema.

Comment: What about method injection ? You can ask for any bean you need. If I understand your post, you don’t want to use IOC but still would like reference of scheme service in report config.

Answer (score 0):

Your logical is a bit strange.
The correct is another service receive ReportConfig. You doing the opposite.

You can work with bean inside another object not spring managed but you need to recreate it.

```
YourService container = (YourService) context.getBean("yourService");
container.load();
```

But it's wrong. The right way is change your logical. Create a generic service with rules to specific reportConfig. Autowire your service and pass your report config and work with that specific data inside the service. (sry my english)

Comment: Why have another service that accepts ReportConfig when my ReportService does little else other than point to a factory that creates a ReportConfig?

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but I'm trying to avoid "feature envy" which is why I make my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could think of wrapping your services in static holder classes

```java
public class SchemaServiceHolder {

   private static final SchemaServiceHolder INSTANCE = new SchemaServiceHolder();

   @Autowired
   private SchemaService schemaService;

   private SchemaServiceHolder () {
   }

   public static SchemaServiceHolder instance() {
      return INSTANCE;
   }

   public SchemaService getSchemaService() {
      return schemaService;
   }
}
```

You then need to create a bean of this type so Spring can inject the service into the singleton `SchemaServiceHolder.INSTANCE`

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
   @Bean
   public SchemaServiceHolder schemaServiceHolder () {
      return SchemaServiceHolder.instance();
   }
}
```

And finally, your objects can reference the `schemaService` statically

```java
SchemaService schemaService = SchemaServiceHolder.instance().getSchemaService();
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution in your case to " also a way to inject SchemaService straight into ReportConfigs, but not sure if this defeats the object..." is to pass the object to the factory.

So basically this line `reportConfigFactory.getReportConfig(request);`
would be changed to this

```
reportConfigFactory.getReportConfig(request, schemaService);
```

It is totally fine to pass the spring managed bean in a constructor of a non managed spring class. In your case is not the constructor directly but to a factory method.